# VS 2012 Express: Team Explorer: Can't create New Team Project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, team-explorer

I've set up the Team Foundation Server. I'm the Administrator with full Permissions on all groups.

I've created a new Collection in the Administration Console and "Allow" Create Projects in the Control Panel

I've installed the Team Explorer that Microsoft says is for VS2012.

When I try to create a "New Team Project" in VS 2012 Express for a Project that I want to add to the Collection I get the following error:

```
TF30172: You are trying to create a team project either without required 
permissions or with an older version of Team Explorer...
```

I've read all the available online information on Team Explorer, they pretty much all skip straight to how to add/check-out/check-in project items to TF, but very inconveniently ignore the how to create a "New Team Project".

How the heck do I do that, when nothing works?

I can't download "Team Explorer 2013 RC" which was the other bit of advice, that no longer exists, I really do not want to install VS 2013 Express, I've wasted so much time with VS 2012 Express and that part of it is now working.

Why, oh why did Microsoft go down the Team Foundation/Team Explorer route when VSS was so easy to set up and manage, and then not allow VSS to be used with VS2012?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Team Project using the same version of Team Explorer as your Team Foundation Server.  If you have TFS 2013, then you need VS 2013; do not get the RC, the release has been out for a long time.

Do not bemoan VSS, it was a fine product in its day, but that day was over a decade ago.

Comment: My problem is, is that the company has a huge VSS library of projects, and it would be much more convenient to add the .NET project files to that library. Can't do that...

Comment: If what you're saying is "it would be convenient if they're all in the same place" then I agree.  But that place shouldn't be VSS.  We made a very handy VSS import tool for TFS for this very reason.

Comment: I've seen the "handy VSS import tool". You don't understand. TFS doesn't work with VS6 (VB6), and VSS doesn't work with VS12.  The vast majority of the code is managed using VS6 and VSS, the company doesn't want to upgrade those projects to VB.NET, only the new stuff is to be coded in VB.NET (VS12)

Comment: VS6 uses a framework called MSSCCI to enable source control integration in the IDE.  TFS provides a MSSCCI provider if you want to continue using VS6 and have source control integration.  If you don't want that integration, you can use standalone Team Explorer.